# How to remove trailing slash from root Wordpress folder?

Tags: url-rewriting, wp-redirect

My WordPress in installed in a folder, https://example.com/folder/.
I would like WP index page to get accessed by https://example.com/folder, however, WP 301 redirects it to https://example.com/folder/.

What do I need to do to get no trailing slash and no redirects when accessing https://example.com/folder?

Comment: From my testing, it appears as though WordPress is doing the redirect but only on the home page if it's a folder. I've tried disabling all plugins, changing themes, adjusting the Permalink, and even adding `DirectorySlash Off | RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash` to the  .htaccess. Nothing works. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Syclone no I didn't ((

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file you could try this below the `RewriteEngine On` line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url

Comment: I've tried it before, doesn't work